# Method of proving counting formula of subspace addition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm following Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler. I understand the proof, but I wish understand the purpose of a step in the proof.

Why did the author change scalars of $(u_1,\dots ,u_m)$ from $a$ to $d$, where $a$ and $d$ are arbitrary scalars? Is this a stylistic change, for easier reading? Or is there some mathematical meaning behind the change of scalars?

The portion of interest is near the last parts of the proof.

---

Theorem:

If $V,W$ are subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space, then
$\dim(V+W)=\dim V+\dim W-\dim(V\cap W)$.

Proof:

Let $V\cap W$ have basis $(u_1,\dots ,u_m)$, with $\dim(V\cap W)=m$.

A basis is linearly independent by definition. Therefore, we can extend the
basis of $V\cap W$ to a basis $(u_1,\dots ,u_m,v_1\dots ,v_j)$ of $V$, with
$\dim V=m+j$.

We also extend the basis of $V\cap W$ to a basis $(u_1,\dots ,u_m,w_1\dots
,w_k)$ of $W$, with $\dim W=m+k$.

Let $union$ be the list of vectors $(u_1,\dots ,u_m,v_1,\dots ,v_j,w_1,\dots
,w_k)$. We will show that $union$ is a basis of $V+W$. Doing so will complete
the proof because:

$$\dim(V+W)=m+j+k=(m+j)+(m+k)-m=\dim V+\dim W-\dim(V\cap W)$$

$span(union)$ contains $V$ and $W$, hence $span(union)$ contains $V+W$.
We need to show that $union$ is linearly independent, in order to show that
$union$ is a basis of $V+W$.

To show this, suppose all $a,b,c$ are scalars. We need to prove that all the
$a=b=c=0$.

$$a_1u_1+\dots +a_mu_m+b_1v_1+\dots +b_jv_j+c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k=0$$
$$c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k=-a_1u_1-\dots -a_mu_m-b_1v_1-\dots -b_jv_j$$

Hence, $c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k\in V$. All $w\in W$, so $c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k\in V\cap W$.

Because $(u_1,\dots ,u_m)$ is a basis of $V\cap W$, for some scalars d,

$$c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k=d_1u_1+\dots +d_mu_m$$

But $(u_1,\dots ,u_m,w_1,\dots ,w_k)$ is linearly independent, so the last equation implies all $c=d=0$. Our original equation involving $a,b,c$ becomes:

$$a_1u_1+\dots +a_mu_m+b_1v_1+\dots +b_jv_j=0$$

Because $(u_1,\dots ,u_m,v_1\dots ,v_j)$ is linearly independent, all $a=b=0$. Hence, $a=b=c=0$, as desired.

Comment: It's a mathematical change. It's not true a priori, that the set of scalars a and d are the same.

Comment: This question means that you don't understand the proof!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Ah of course... after some thinking I finally got it. Thanks! Should I remove this question, since the answer is so trivial?

Comment: It's good that you thought yourself and got it. If you have got it, write an answer below, and call me, so that I can critique it. Then, you can accept the answer yourself, and close this question, rather than have it float around since it is resolved.

Comment: You are welcome. When you can do so, accept your answer and close this question, since it is resolved. Also, if you like this site, do use it more often!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both $(w_1,\dots ,w_k)$ and $(u_1,\dots ,u_m)$ are bases of same subspace $V\cap W$, each basis must be linearly independent.

Hence there is a unique set of scalars $c,d$ for each basis to represent a linear combination of any vector in the subspace. Let this vector be $x$.

$$c_1w_1+\dots +c_kw_k=x=d_1u_1+\dots +d_mu_m$$

The set of scalars $d$ could be, but is not constrained to, the set of scalars $a$. Again using the unique representation of vectors,

$$d_1u_1+\dots +d_mu_m=-a_1u_1-\dots -a_mu_m-b_1v_1-\dots -b_jv_j$$

(The linear combination of vectors $u\in V\cap W$ and $v\in V$, is in subspace $V\cap W$, by analogy to the similar proof for vector $w\in W$ being in subspace $V\cap W$.)

Comment: This answer is fine.